# Fetching Group Subscribers in SSJS script (ExactTarget)

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm struggling on finding a way to fetch Subscribers in a Group inside of a SSJS used as part of an Automation Studio campaign.

I've figured out how to do this using a List:

```
var lists = List.Retrieve({Property:"ID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:listID});
listKey = lists[0].CustomerKey; 
var myList = List.Init(listKey);
var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve();
```

I tried passing the Group ID as the listID, but the system doesn't find my Group. I thought this would work because in the SOAP API/Fuel SDK I can use ListSubscribers to fetch subscribers of either a List or Group by providing the ID. Unfortunately SSJS doesn't seem to have the same behavior.

Is there a different way to get Group Subscribers in an SSJS script (assuming I have the Group ID or CustomerKey)?

Comment: Can you talk more specifically about how you're using the SSJS?  It's designed to be used only on landing pages, and I want to make sure that is the case here.

Comment: No. Nothing with landing pages. It is used in an automation studio campaign to trigger an external script using an HTTP Post.

I've actually given up on this approach for the time being and have decided to simply post the Group ID to my external endpoint then use the fuel SDK to do the actual subscriber retrieval. Really this is probably better architecturally as I can handle a large volume of subscribers.

So, if there is a way to get Group subscribers in an SSJS I'd be interested out of curiosity, but it's no longer necessary for my solution.